# Can I replace QR front wheel with bolt-on?

Tags: rims, quick-release

The 27x1 1/4 steel QR front wheel on my 1985 Raleigh Grand Prix has a bend; not just not true, it is bent.  I cannot find a replacement wheel, but have a 27x1 1/4 steel wheel with a bolt-on axel.  Is there any problem or consideration in replacing a quick-release wheel with a bolt-on wheel?
Also, the bent wheel is original; is there any possibility of repairing the smoothly bent rim?

Comment: How concerned are you with originality on this bike build?   It is possible to somewhat straighten a steel rim, but its a lot of work.  Do you want to put ~10 hours into this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the threaded axle wheel fits in the dropouts and you can tighten bolts against the dropouts, there is no problem usung it.

If your rim is actually deformed, as in if you loosened all the spokes it would remain significantly untrue, then you will not be able to re-build a wheel with it.

Comment: Thanks.  It is deformed.  Too bad, it matches the rear and has texturing on the rim where the brake touches.

Comment: If the rim material is steel rather than aluminium you'd better try to find suitable new wheels. Steel rims have a notoriously bad braking behaviour when wet. (Even though this might go against the vintage look.)